# How to select X consecutive numbers of rows meeting a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I the following table:

```
 ID          TIMESLOT_ID   SLOTS_AVAILABLE
 1               1               10
 2               3               2
 3               8               3
 4               9               10
 5               2               10
 6               6               10
 7               4               10
```

I want to perform a query where I can get all rows where SLOTS_AVAILABLE is equal or greater than (user_input_1) AND the next (user_input_2) consecutive rows following to that one meet the same condition (SLOTS_AVAILABLE is equal or greater than (user_input_1))

So if (user_input_1) is 3 and (user_input_2) is 3 the result would be:

```
 ID          TIMESLOT_ID   SLOTS_AVAILABLE
 3               8               3
 4               9               10
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry! just did =)

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  8.0.18 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: Oh. A CSS update.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when slots_available >= :user_input_1 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by id
                  rows between current row and :user_input_2 following
                 ) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = :user_input_2 + 1;
```

This requires MySQL 8+.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be24d3a16488b683cba24fb22a675d6d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: got a mysql error: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows
                 ) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 3 + 1 LIMIT' at line 5

Comment: @GabrielDube . . . I fixed the syntax error and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you so much! Is there a way to only select the rows that match those conditions without creating another column?

Comment: @GabrielDube . . . Just select the columns you want in the outer query.

Comment: thank you! it worked fine. If I was going to update the rows where slots_available meet that condition, would I follow the same structure?

Comment: @GabrielDube . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, if you can't figure it out.  It requires joining the results of this query back to the original table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228495/discussion-between-gabriel-dube-and-gordon-linoff).